# Drag and Drop with HTML5, MVC and Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, html5-draggable

I'm using MVC 5 and Entity Framework 6 to create a web application where users can file a report and assign a category to it. A report can have multiple categories and a category can have multiple reports, so a many to many relation.

```
public class Report
{
    public int ReportID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Report> Reports { get; set; }
}
```

Entity Framework creates the bridge table, but isn't very helpful in scaffolding the views to manage the relations between the entities.

So, for the Edit and Create views of `Report` I've implemented the functionality from [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/Q1K7KeLYPM8?t=1444) to create two MultiSelectList boxes that contain assigned categories and available categories. The categories are moved from one list to the other with some javascript and with custom code in the controllers I update the database.

This is working fine, but what I really want is a Drag and Drop application, where the user can drag a `Category` from a sidebar with available categories to the `Report` to assign it.

I installed the JQuery Draggable and Droppable plugins, but later discovered HTML5 drag and drop functionality. I found many nice tutorials and managed to get some basic drag and drop functionality going on the page, but none of the tutorials covered updating the underlying database. Now I'm really struggling to find a good way to pass the assigned categories back to the controller like I did with the listboxes.

This is what I have so far:

```
// sidebar with available categories
<aside>
    <label class="control-label">Available Categories</label>
    <br/>
    <ul class="AvailableCategories">
        @foreach (var cat in ViewBag.availCats)
        {
            <li value="@cat.CategoryID" class="category">@cat.CategoryTitle</li>
        }
    </ul>
</aside>

// form group with selected categories
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Categories, "Categories", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <ul class="AssignedCategories" id="assignedCategories" style="width:500px;height:100px;border:1px solid black">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

// make the elements draggable/sortable
$(function () {
    $('.AvailableCategories').sortable({
        connectWith: '.AssignedCategories'
    });

    $('.AssignedCategories').sortable({
        connectWith: '.AvailableCategories'
    });
});

// old functionality with listboxes
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label class="control-label">Categories Assigned</label>
    @Html.ListBox("selectedOptions", (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.selCats, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>

// controller
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ReportID,Name,Description,CategoryID")] Report report, string[] selectedOptions, string[] assignedCategories)
{
    // selectedOptions is populated from the old listboxes
    // assignedCategories is always null
}
```

This enables dragging and dropping a `Category` from one list to the other, but when the `Report` is saved I'm not able to catch the assigned Categories in the ReportController ActionResult and update the database. I created a parameter `string[] assignedCategories`, hoping this would bind to `id="assignedCategories"` like it did for the listboxes, but this parameter is always `null`.

What is the best way to populate the `Report.Categories` collection and update the database with HTML5 drag and drop functionality, using MVC and Entity Framework? Any help or a link to a good tutorial would be appreciated.

**Update:**
I was not using a proper form input field for the assignedCategories and the model binder is looking for the name, not the id. That's why the assignedCategories was null. So, I've created a hidden input field with `name="assignedCategories"` and I update the value with javascript each time a Category is dropped in the assigned categories. Now I'm able to collect a list of assigned CategoryID's and process it in the controller.

Still, there must be a better way of doing this. What kind of form input can I use to drop the assigned categories on?